# PyCharm indica error al importar librerias

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Acabo de actualizar **PyCharm Professional** a la ultima versión (2020.1) y me indica errores de importación de algunas librerias, sobretodo las de Django. El código funciona perfectamente, lo único que indica es `Unresolved reference 'libreria'` y lo subraya de rojo. A parte, el autocompletado no funciona en algunas ocasiones.

He mirado en los ajustes, por si había alguna forma de solucionarlo pero no he encontrado nada, tampoco en la documentación de la página de JetBrains.

[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

Lo unico que se me ocurre es que instales django, ya que trata de importar algunos modulos de django que no existen

Pega esto en cmd para descargar django:

```
git clone https://github.com/django/django.git
```